# PHP Websocket. Send message on close?

Tags: php, websocket

I use workerman/workerman for websockets.
The main question – how to send messages on websocket closing?
Also I tried to send messages to other connections. No result too.

```
    public function run()
    {
        $this->ws = new Worker(
            'websocket://0.0.0.0:' . $_ENV['WS_PORT'],
            ['ssl' => [
                'local_cert'  => $_ENV['WS_CERTIFICATE_CRT'],
                'local_pk'    => $_ENV['WS_CERTIFICATE_KEY'],
                'verify_peer' => false,
            ]]
        );
        $this->ws->count = 1;
        $this->ws->transport = 'ssl';

        $this->ws->onConnect = function ($connection) {
            $this->onConnect($connection);
        };

        $this->ws->onMessage = function ($connection, $data) {
            $this->onMessage($connection, $data);
        };

        $this->ws->onClose = function ($connection) {
            $this->onClose($connection);
        };

        Worker::runAll();
    }
```

This doesn't work

```
private function onClose($connection)
{
    $connection->send("Hello");
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can reliably send a message when a websocket is being closed. Why not send a packet indicating that the connection should be closed? You can run your logic and then close the socket on your side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code of workerman/workerman we can see that the `onClose` event is implemented as [follows](https://github.com/walkor/workerman/blob/master/src/Connection/TcpConnection.php#L1000):

```php
        // Close socket.
        try {
            @fclose($this->socket);
        } catch (Throwable) {
        }

        $this->status = self::STATUS_CLOSED;
        // Try to emit onClose callback.
        if ($this->onClose) {
            try {
                ($this->onClose)($this);
            } catch (Throwable $e) {
                $this->error($e);
            }
        }
```

As you can see, `onClose` is emitted AFTER the socket has been closed.

So you will not be able to use that socket in your `onClose` handler anymore.

A better solution would be that the client sends some sort of "close" packet to the server.

The server can then run some logic and close the connection after it is done.

Comment: but can i still get $connection->id?

Comment: @denismart Sure, but that doesn't mean it's valid or that you should use that id.